# ini_set doesn't overwrite php settings

Tags: php, file-upload

I am trying upload larger files so I set this in php code

```
    ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '1000M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '1100M');
ini_set('memory_limit', '1200M');
```

but $_POST and $_FILES are empty. But when I change php.ini settings it works. Why it doesn't change setting on the fly?

Comment: is it VPS or Shared Hosting or Localhost?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's too late to have those settings changed after PHP has started.

- `upload_max_filesize` - uploads happen *before* the PHP script runs and your ini_set() is executed
- `post_max_size` - likewise

And even if you could change `memory_limit` (depends on server configuration), it would be too late again if you expect that big of an upload.

See [`ini_set()`](http://php.net/ini_set) and http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php for more info.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at these :

http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php

After reading, it seems that the only option that you can modify with `ini_set` is `memory_limit`. 
The others 2 being configurable in the php.ini file, in httpd.conf, .htaccess, or in a per directory .user.ini file.

Meaning, if you want to change these values, you must have access to your server's configuration ! You won't be able to afford that from within the script !

Answer (score 1):

The first two settings are not allowed to be changed per script, but even if they *were* it still would not be effective since the files/POST data must be handled *before the script is even run*, which means that the settings wouldn't have a chance to take effect.